c# I want to assign the S key to the button, but I can't
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Button button;

    void Start()
    {
        button = GetComponent<Button>();
        button.onClick.AddListener(OnButtonClick);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.S))
        {
            button.onClick.Invoke();
        }
    }

    void OnButtonClick()
    {
        // Butona tıklandığında yapılacak işlemler
        Debug.Log("Button clicked!");
    }
}

I tried this code but it didn't work. Can anyone guide me?

"but it didn't work" - please be more specific.
